# Visual Studio 2017 ClickOnce Certificate Signing Disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, certificate, signing

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017 (15.7.3). I need to sign my project with a certificate while developing to avoid our security software complaining every time I build and run it. When I open the Properties for the project and select the Signing tab, the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" checkbox is grayed out -- in fact every single item on that page is grayed out except for the "Sign the assembly" checkbox.

How do I add a certificate to this project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?.

Comment: Still no answer? I have the same problem.

Comment: from what i saw its enabled for exes but disabled for libraries

Comment: This is still happening in 2024 using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition.